# Get data from usb from php with raspberry

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, usb

I've a problem. I need to know how to get data from an usb stick from php thats running on raspberry pi. I have to display the data in a webpage. With data I mean an video (mp4 or something else)

What is the best way to do it, and how can I build this.
I appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: Remember, that a USB stick is just a directory in the file system, like every other. Thus, if it is mounted, you can access it like every other directory.